# Class Methods Using Singleton in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, singleton

When using singleton's I run into the same code over and over, something like:

`[[SomeManager sharedInstance] stringForKey:@"someKey"];`

In my opinion it would be cleaner just to write `[SomeManager stringForKey:@"someKey"];`

My current IMPL of the `stringForKey` method is:

```
- (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (self.localeDictionary) {
        return [self stringByStrippingHTML:[self safeStringForKey:key]];
    } else return nil;
}
```

If I just change it to a class method, I get several errors. I can alleviate all of the errors by writing:

```
+ (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key {
    SomeManager *theManager = [SomeManager sharedManager];
    if (theManager.localeDictionary) {
        return [theManager.localeDictionary stringByStrippingHTML:[theManager.localeDictionary safeStringForKey:key]];
    } else return nil;
}
```

My question is whether or not I'm doing it horribly wrong.

Edit: Update class method with local var.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, so long as it's not in a performance-critical section of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get errors, because in a class method "self" is not an instance, but the class - [self whatEver] in a class method of class MyClass is the same as the class method [MyClass whatEver].

I personally would hate to make three calls to [SomeManager sharedManager] in three lines of code. Not the least because it makes debugging a nightmare. Just assign the sharedManager to a local variable.

Comment: Updated the question using the local variable. Is that new way of doing it better or worse than doing `[[SomeManager sharedManager] stringForKey];`